# Iterate python list and sum equal items

Tags: python, json

Considering a endpoint on my backend, that returns the following response:

```
class Arc_Edges_Data(Resource):
  def get(self):
        #Connect to databse
        conn = connectDB()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        #Perform query and return JSON data
        try:
          cur.execute("select json_build_object('source', start_location, 'target', end_location, 'frequency', 1) from trips")
        except:
          print("Error executing select")
        ArcList = list (i[0] for i in cur.fetchall())
        return ArcList
```

The frequency here is supposed to be always of 1 for each trip. So this `ArcList` originates a response like this:

```
[
    {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "c", 
        "target": "c"
    }, 
    {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "a", 
        "target": "b"
    }, {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "a", 
        "target": "b"
    }, ...
]
```

How can I iterate this response and sum the items that have the same `source` and `target`? In this case, the resulting list would have only one pair source/target with "a" and "b", but the frequency would be 2, because of the sum.

I know that for Javascript I could use something like `Array.reduce`, but I don't think it exists for Python.

Comment: python has reduce https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: Python Counter may help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
import collections

data = [
    {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "c", 
        "target": "c",
    }, 
    {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "a", 
        "target": "b",
    },
    {
        "frequency": 1, 
        "source": "a", 
        "target": "b",
    },
]

counter = collections.Counter()

for datum in data:
    counter[(datum['source'], datum['target'])] += datum['frequency']

print(counter)

# Output:
# Counter({('a', 'b'): 2, ('c', 'c'): 1})
```

Oh, if you want to put the data back into the same format again, add this code:

```
newdata = [{
    'source': k[0],
    'target': k[1],
    'frequency': v,
} for k, v in counter.items()]

print(newdata)

# Output:
# [{'frequency': 1, 'target': 'c', 'source': 'c'}, {'frequency': 2, 'target': 'b', 'source': 'a'}]
```

Comment: This works perfectly! But I've also read what @Brendan Abel said and which way is the most efficient for a large dataset?

Comment: @Shoplifter.Doe I haven't tested their performance, but my guess is that they're very close to identical.

Comment: Ok thank you, I can always come back an check the other way if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
r = {}
for d in ArcList:
    key = (d['source'], d['target'])
    r[key] = r.setdefault(key, 0) + d['frequency']
return [{'source': k[0], 'target': k[1], 'frequency': v} for k, v in r.items()]
```

If you want to preserve the original ordering of the items:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
r = OrderedDict()
# The rest of the solution is the same
...
```

Comment: This is equivalent to my answer but using a `dict` instead of a `Counter`. (I personally prefer `Counter`, just because the intent of the code is clearer, but there's nothing wrong with this answer.)

Comment: @smarx Yeah, I thought of using Counter, but it doesn't really work if `frequency` isn't always 1.  You're basically just using Counter like a regular dict, though it is nice that it works like a `defaultdict` without the need for `setdefault`

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't really work if `frequency` isn't always 1?"

Comment: @smarx Generally, they way I would use counter would be to just feed it a list of values and let it do the counting.  In this case, we're not really counting the number of occurrences of `source/target`, we're adding up all the frequency values (unless frequency was always 1, in which case the count and the frequency total would be the same)

Comment: That's fine but not the only way to use a `Counter`. In my use, it's basically just a dictionary with the default value 0.